# How to start container with Docker.DotNet (NET CORE)

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core

I try to use NET CORE package https://github.com/dotnet/Docker.DotNet to start docker container from NET CORE.

Usually my command line looks as

```
sudo docker run -it \
--name digiwage.$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S) \
--expose='46003' \
-e RPC_PASSWORD=$(xxd -l 32 -c 32 -p /dev/urandom) \
-e EXTERNAL_IP='157.XX.XX.85' \
-e MASTERNODE_PRIV_KEY='51kWXqrknGeLLEqnUgRBPtrBxQ3o5VBp4bkRy4fHN3ZpzURHdkr' \
-e TX_INDEX='1' \
-e SEED_NODE='95.XX.XX.73' \
-e PORT='46003' \
-e RPC_ALLOW_IP='127.0.0.1' \
-e RPC_CONNECT_IP='127.0.0.1' \
-p '157.XX.XX.85:46003:46003' \
XXXXXX/daemon:latest
```

There are restricted example, how is possible to start it https://github.com/dotnet/Docker.DotNet/blob/master/test/Docker.DotNet.Tests/IContainerOperationsTests.cs

But main point is absent in documentation. Firstly, following docker documentation https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports docker has are two parameters related to port

```
  --expose=[] Expose a port or a range of ports inside the container
  -p=[] Publish a container's port or a range of ports to the host
```

Unfortunately, I don't see in Docker.DotNet two different parameters, related to ports.

[image]

Second issue, this my code produced only template of containers instead working container.

```
    Dim Env = New List(Of String)({"RPC_PASSWORD=$(xxd -l 32 -c 32 -p /dev/urandom)",
                                   "EXTERNAL_IP='157.XX.XX.85'",
                                   "MASTERNODE_PRIV_KEY='51kWXqrknGeLLEqnUgRBPtrBxQ3o5VBp4bkRy4fHN3ZpzURHdkr'",
                                   "TX_INDEX='1'",
                                   "SEED_NODE='95.XX.XX.73'",
                                   "PORT='46004'",
                                   "RPC_ALLOW_IP='127.0.0.1'",
                                   "RPC_CONNECT_IP='127.0.0.1'"})
    Dim ExposedPorts = New Dictionary(Of String, EmptyStruct)
    ExposedPorts.Add("'157.XX.XX.85:46004:46004'", New EmptyStruct)
    Dim Prm = New CreateContainerParameters With {
                  .Image = "alexev275/digiwage:latest",
                  .Name = $"digiwage.{Guid.NewGuid}",
                  .Env = Env,
                  .ExposedPorts = ExposedPorts,
                  .Tty = True
    }
    Dim CreateContainer As CreateContainerResponse = DockerHub.Containers.CreateContainerAsync(Prm).Result
    Dim StartResTask As Task(Of Boolean) = DockerHub.Containers.StartContainerAsync(CreateContainer.ID, New ContainerStartParameters())
    StartResTask.Wait()
```

[image]

I don't receive errors or warning, only Status=RunToCompletion and template of container without starting.

[image]

How to really start container by https://github.com/dotnet/Docker.DotNet ?
And how to set correct parameters --expose=[] and -p=[] ?

Comment: You have two issues here: 1. your containers are exiting as soon as you start them 2. you don't know how to expose ports. Those should be 2 different questions. Anyway, you need to find the container logs and read any errors/messages logged to figure out how to fix problem 1. It might have to do with `RPC_PASSWORD=$(xxd -l 32 -c 32 -p /dev/urandom)`, which is evaluated by bash to produce a random password, but it's a literal string in .NET.

Comment: Thank you, @omajid. This is answer, of course you are right, I replace RPC_PASSWORD to normal .NET function, container started and of course you are right about log. I see log and see "Error: Invalid -rpcallowip subnet specification: '127.0.0.1'. Valid are a single IP, a network/netmask or a network/CIDR". Therefore I understand character ' need to use only for bash escaping. I also delete single quote mark and my container started! However publishing ports in docker host still wrong . This is another question. Please, set your remark as replay and I will mark your replay as solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues here:

1. your containers are exiting as soon as you start them
2. you don't know how to expose ports.

Those should be 2 different questions.

Anyway, you need to find the container logs and read any errors/messages logged to figure out how to fix problem 1. It might have to do with `RPC_PASSWORD=$(xxd -l 32 -c 32 -p /dev/urandom)`, which is evaluated by bash to produce a random password, but it's a literal string in .NET.